# Get selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fetch the selected option from dropdown. I know I can get selected option with jQuery(dropdown).val(). But I am not able fetch the selected with the 'val' function.

[image]

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: please use $(".your Classname").val() this will help to get dropdown value. Or write your code in your question image is not properly visible.

Comment: add your tried code and fiddle

Comment: Your suggested code is also not working. Can you open the image in the new window?

Comment: $($daterangePreset).val() doesn't work?

Comment: @Wilmer no it's not working

Comment: $().jquery return anything?

Comment: @Wilmer Please find attached new image in the question. You can see I have tried your suggested changes there.

Comment: @krunalshah, please post your generated html here, rather than images, or create fiddle.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/uAF7x/

Comment: Yes that's the problem I don't understand. It works perfectly fine in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @krunalshah: is your dropdown build dynamiclly??? or have you try $(".your Classname").val() to put in $(document).ready(){ function(){}}

Comment: @YashPatel Yes, dropdown build dynamically.

Comment: @krunalshah so you must put you code in document ready or after completing building of dropdown.
can you show me ur source..??

Comment: @YashPatel Thank you so much for your help. The issue was in my code. I have explained the issue in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
var selectedValue = $('.daterange-preset').val();
```

(Note: I was able to see your code and get your class name by zooming in, but in the future please post the code rather than a screenshot.)

Answer (score 0):

try using .on( "change" and then finding the option where selected has been applied. I have attached a jsfiddle with a working example that will alert you the value of the selected option everytime you change it.

```
$('.datarange-preset').on( "change", function(){
      var datarangeSelected = $('.datarange-preset').find(":selected").val();  
        alert(datarangeSelected);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8hVA/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. In my code at one place dropdown value was getting set with the null.

```
$daterangePreset.val(someVarialwithNullValue);
```

Because the value was getting set with null. I don't see any update in the HTML. HTML still shows one of the option as 'selected'. So when I was trying to get the selected value with following syntax it was always returning null.

```
$daterangePreset.val();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variant of:

```
  var text = $("option:selected").text();
  var value = $("option:selected").val();
```